# Carriage Return in Excel that Outlook Recognizes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, outlook

I'm building a inventory tracker in excel that will populate an email in outlook to notify the inventory manager to reduce stock. It seems as though excel won't let me put a carriage return where I would like it. The formula is as follows:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&D15&"?subject=Inventory Reduction,&cc="&B15&"&body=Hello,%0APlease reduce the following from inventory.%0A%0A"&B5&C5&D5&F5,"SUBMIT")
```

I would like another carriage return after F5 so I can start a new line of cells.

(EDIT):

I changed the code to this:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&D15&"?subject=Inventory Reduction,&cc="&B15&"&body=Hello,%0APlease reduce the following from inventory.%0A%0ARaw Materials   Part Number  Lot Number   LBS%0A"&B6&C6&D6&F6&"%0A"&B7&C7&D7&F7,"SUBMIT")
```

Now I can get two lines of the table into the email. But, when I try and repeat the process for line 8 it returns #VALUE.

Comment: Please show the error you're seeing and the code that prompts it.

Comment: You would add ```&"%0A" after F5```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&D15&"?subject=Inventory Reduction,&cc="&B15&"&body=Hello,%0APlease reduce the following from inventory.%0A%0ARaw Materials Part Number Lot Number LBS%0A"&B6&C6&D6&F6&"%0A"&B7&C7&D7&F7&"%0A"&B8&C8&D8&F8,"SUBMIT")
```

Just double check your formula.